# open the response uri after the authentication passes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, ntlm

I'm opening a NTLM authenticated site via a MVC app.

```
public ActionResult Login(Credentials data)
{
    Uri queryUrl = new Uri("http://someurl.com");

    string domain = "DMZ";

    HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(queryUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
    NetworkCredential cred = new NetworkCredential(data.UName, data.Pass, domain);
    var cache = new CredentialCache { { queryUrl, "Ntlm", cred } };
    req.Credentials = cache;
    HttpWebResponse response = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;


    return Redirect(response.ResponseUri.OriginalString);
    //return View();
}
```

if i put a break point on return, i do get the response.statuscode as "OK", the authentication is working fine. but i don't know how to open the url with the authentication. With the redirect I'm using its asking for credentials again.

Comment: Why would you do this?

Comment: we have a uri that uses Ntlm authentication, when you go to the site it asks for the user name and password the default login screen. we want to have a custom login page with the agreement on.